# PowerDNS, returns SOA record only

Tags: domain-name-system, powerdns

I have setup powerdns server, I'm satisfied with basic functionalities.

users in my domain are unable to access example.com unless they use www.example.com

when I use host command

```
 host example.com 127.0.0.1
```

I get

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.10.rc1.el6_3.6 <<>> @localhost example.com
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 45277
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.INA

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.com.300INSOAdns.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. 1 86400 86400 604800 300

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Jan 29 11:06:15 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 80
```

the query doesn't return server ip only when I use www.example.com or ftp.example.com is there is a work around for this?

Thanks

Comment: Well, do you have a record for `@` in the zone file?

Comment: no I don't @ and it should point to my server IP?

Comment: I have added @  with type "A" to point to my server IP, and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: If the suggestions here and in the first answer below don't help, you need to show us a lot more. Please include pdns.conf and any referenced files, and any relevant database dumps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OKay, I have found a solution, if you are using a nice UI such as (PowerDNS Webinterface) to manage your powerDNS server, you need to create an "empty" A record pointing to your IP address

example

1. Add new record.
2. Under value section "leave it empty" this will resemble the @ root zone file and have it point to your DNS IP address.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a root zone record. It is usually denoted `@` and must be a host record, CNAME's can not be used

`@` references the zone name itself, so if you need to resolve `example.com` you need a record named `@` in the root of the zone `example.com`

Comment: unfortunately this didn't resolve my issue, I have added @ type A record and point to my server's IP address. but it is still giving me same host or dig results.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify which PowerDNS backend you used.

The @ syntax as mentioned by several people here does only work with the bind backend that uses BIND-style zonefiles.

If you used for example gmysql as a backend you would need to create a record by the name of "example.com" and the IP address you want it to point to as the content.